# Apply texture to sphere without wide seems (Babylonjs)

Tags: babylonjs

With babylonjs I'm trying to apply the diffuse cubemap texture file included in te .obj file here:

https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/realistic-mars-photorealistic-2k-3d-1277433

with:

```
this.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('mars', scene);
this.material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("./assets/mesh/Mars/Diffuse.png", scene);
this.material.diffuseTexture.hasAlpha = true;
```

If I set `hasAlpha` to false the seems just get filled in with stretched out texture.

[image]

I assumed texture would be applied more precisely. How can I get rid on these wide seems?

Comment: Hi there, try setting this: `BABYLON.OBJFileLoader.OPTIMIZE_WITH_UV = true;` before the scene loads. (from https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/obj)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a UV mapping issue. How did you created your sphere ? Do you have a babylon-playground example ?

Don't hesitate to go to the babylon forum for further informations :
https://forum.babylonjs.com/c/questions

Comment: The sphere was downloaded form here: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/realistic-mars-photorealistic-2k-3d-1277433